# Random Session Drop/Redirect Homepage on Final Payline Checkout Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

We recently ran into a very difficult bug to diagnose.  A customer will browse the website, add items to their cart, go to the checkout, and select Payline credit card.  When they press the final "Place Order" button on the onepage checkout screen, they will get directed to "GET /payline/index/cpt/", but then randomly get redirected to the homepage.  Their entire session will be lost and they will need to completely redo the checkout process again.  We thought it was an issue with the Payline checkout screen so we setup a ton of debugging in the payline script itself, but found out that the module is never hit when the redirect is triggered.  The main observer is not loaded from what we can tell.  The user just gets redirected to the homepage and their cart/session is lost).

The redirect SHOULD go to the Payline secure online checkout screen (similar to PayPal).

All the items we have checked:

1. Session Validation Disabled
2. Form key disabled
3. Disabled optimization on the onepage checkout
4. No discernible pattern of browsers: Chrome/Firefox on Mobile/Desktop/Tablets, on Laptops/tablets/mobile phones.
5. No errors in any of the Magento logs (exception/system) nor in any of the webserver logs.

The question would be what steps should we try to trace the calls to the module.  Any other suggestions as to what else the issue might be?

Comment: We just rolled back the following patches and we have not had any failures at all.  We are going to add each patch and wait for the failure to occur.
SUPEE-8788
SUPEE-8976
SUPEE-7405-v1
SUPEE-7405-v1.1
SUPEE-9652
SUPEE-9767
SUPEE-10336
SUPEE-10266
SUPEE-10415
SUPEE-10570

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
Revert patch 10570 v1.
Apply patch 10570 v2.
```

Good luck!

Comment: What about checkout issues?  How do I know that will fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - install the patch 10572 and note the "note".

> Conflicts during installation of the patch SUPEE-10752 are caused most
>   often by having version 1 of the previous patch installed
>   (SUPEE-10570v1). Please make sure to remove SUPEE-10570v1 and install
>   SUPEE-10570v2 prior to installation of SUPEE-10752.

Now is works fine ...

Link: [Magento Security - supee-10752](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10752)

Comment: Right, but there is no mention of checkout issues.

Comment: You can patch with supee-10752 OR upgrade to 1.9.3.9. 

In 1.9.3.9 Releasenotes can you see the fixes Issue ... "Customers can now successfully register during checkout without being unexpectedly logged out."

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html?#ce19-1939

I think - The checkout-issue is based at the patch 10570v1.

Comment: @Dierk Landmann we just ran into this bug in 1.9.3.8 and we spent almost 2 days trying to fix it until we realized of this magento bug. 1.9.3.9 is suposed to fix it, but in our case, 1.9.3.9 keeps redirecting home without finishing the checkout, same as 1.9.3.8. So we tried 1.9.3.7 that works fine, and 1.9.3.8 with the 10570V2 patch that also works fine. But 1.9.3.9 keeps is still failing, so it is supposed to be fixed, but at least in our project it is not fixed. Finally we had to use 1.9.3.8 with the patch.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in EE v1.14.2.4. I applied the following patches in this order:

1. SUPEE-10570v2
   (PATCH_SUPEE-10570_EE_v1.14.2.4_v2-2018-03-22-10-57-00.sh)
2. SUPEE-10752
   (PATCH_SUPEE-10752_EE_v1.14.2.4_v1-2018-06-25-09-53-38.sh)
3. invalid_session_fix-2018-03-14-05-10-19.patch

The last patch is found in https://magento.com/tech-resources/download under **SUPEE-10570** > **invalid_session_fix.patch (0 MB)**